# For which constants $a$ function is continuous

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x)= \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot\cos{(a\cdot x)}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Find for which real constants $a$ function is continuous.

We know function $ \lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous apart from integers and $\cos x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ so we want to make $f(x)= \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot\cos{(a\cdot x)}$ continuous at integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose you had found such an $a$.  Then $f$ is continuous, as is $x\mapsto \cos (ax)$.  Thus, $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{\cos(ax)}=\lfloor x \rfloor$ is continuous everywhere where $\cos(ax)\neq 0$.  Use this to determine $a$ (or show that the condition can't be fulfilled by any $a$!)

Comment: so $a$ must be such that $\cos(ax)=0$  so then $\displaystyle a=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2n}$ ?? but how to chose it to be const ?

Comment: but if $a=\pi$ then $\cos(ax) \neq 0$

Comment: @Thomas Sorry about that, just realized I was thinking about sine for some reason. XD

Comment: @Thomas Now that I have my head screwed on straight, the ultimate answer is that you can't choose $a$ to be constant.  If we want $\cos (ax)=0$ at $x=0$, then this would necessitate that $\cos 0=0$, which is certainly not true.  So there can't exist such an $a$.